# How do I stop my school from configuring policies?

Tags: lan, group-policy, regedit

My school stops my computer from getting windows updates and prevents the use of lots of other tasks. I have an admin account on my computer so that isn’t a problem. Every time I make a local change then connect to the internet at school the policies are updated to what the school has set.

Comment: There's a good reason for this. Imagine if all the students had free reign to install whatever they want, personalize the machine to their liking... it's a nightmare to maintain as a sys admin. Having access to install windows updates is risky too, corporations and schools like to test the impact of a KB before rolling them out via WSUS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Comment: Is it your *personal* PC or a *school-provided* one? If its school provided and **not your property** then you don't (and shouldn't) have to change it - you should run it by them first, as it might be on purpose. Even more so with windows updates as it might break something that they rely on...

Comment: personal pc and i can already install everything i want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

If you came here looking for a list of admin commands to block group policy updates, you'll be disappointed.